# Showing the amount of search results when using exp:low_search:popular

Tags: low-search

Can I show the amount of search results when using exp:low_search:popular?
And I would like to sort by the amount of search results if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the actual amount of search results if you were to search your site with those keywords at that moment? If so, no, that's not possible. Performance would take a nosedive (as you're performing X searches in one go, where X is the amount of popular keywords) and you'd have to take other filters into account too, which could differ in countless ways.